# why does the value of the variant 'sum' change after passing the function 'pthread_create()'?

Tags: c, pthreads, verification

I declared a variant `sum` and initialized to **0**, then I pass it to the function `func()` through the function `pthread_create()`. What I didn't expect was the variant `sum` didn't equal to **0** any more (as you can see, the function `assert()` was failed). My ubuntu is 16.04.4 LTS.

> It is all right when I just use **GCC** to compile it, the error was reported by **CBMC**.

```
static void * func(void * arg)
{
  double *sum = (double *)arg;

  assert(*sum == 0.0);  //failed in CBMC
  return ((void *) 0);
}

int main(){

  double sum=0.0;
  pthread_t thr1;

  pthread_create(&thr1, NULL, &func, (void *)&sum );
  pthread_join(thr1, NULL);

  printf("sum = %f\n", sum);
  assert(sum == 0.0);   //successful in CBMC

  return 0;
}
```

> Following are the warning reported by **CBMC**:

```
State 70 file pthreads4.c line 24 function main thread 1
----------------------------------------------------
  arg=&sum!0@1 (0000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)

State 71 file pthreads4.c line 12 function func thread 1
----------------------------------------------------
  sum=((double *)NULL) (0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)

State 72 file pthreads4.c line 12 function func thread 1
----------------------------------------------------
  sum=&sum!0@1 (0000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)

Violated property:
  file pthreads4.c line 14 function func
  assertion *sum == 0
  IEEE_FLOAT_EQUAL(*sum, (double)0)

VERIFICATION FAILED
```

Comment: Could you try just for laughs to see if adding `.0` would change anything, i.e. `assert(*sum == 0.0);` ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I can't see much wrong either:(

Comment: The warning reported by CBMC is still the same.

Comment: Why do you expect `assert(sum == 1);` to pass?

Comment: Tested it just works fine on `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4`

Comment: @n.m. I have delete a lot of codes to simplify my program. I'm sorry for my careless and I have modified it.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We have no idea how to reason about a program we cannot see.

Comment: @kiranBiradar But why? Is it a real error?

Comment: Post your code which produces the error.

Comment: @kiranBiradar This is the whole program I used to be verify by CBMC. The error only occur when I use `pthread_create()` to pass argument `sum`.

Comment: @BailinLu There is compilation error in your code   `pthread_t thr1` should be   `pthread_t thr1;`

Comment: @kiranBiradar Thank you. But the error is still existing.

Comment: OK, initialize the sum to, say, 3.14159.   Copy the printf up so that 'sum' gets printed immediately after the init, just to prove that the  '%f' format works OK for a double. Copy the printf into the thread function too and mod it to print out '*sum'.  Comment out the assert() statements.  Now what happens?

Comment: using ubuntu 18.04.1 and gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) with parameters: compiled with: 'gcc -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c"` linked with: 'gcc -ggdb -Wall untitled.o -o "untitled"   -lpthread'; the posted code compiled/linked  with no errors/warnings and worked as expected

Comment: OT:  always check the C library functions to assure no error occurred

Comment: Oh. this is not a code-correctness issue.  CBMC is a model-checker.  It sounds like CBMC needs to be informed about the argument-passing semantics of pthread_create.  There should either be a way to extend the tool's default rules, or to annotate assumptions onto the thread function for what the range of `arg` (and/or `*arg`) can be.  It also might be a fundamental limitation of the tool, as testing a static assertion on the value of a pointer requires a full data-flow analysis, which is typically intractable in C.

Comment: @MartinJames  Both of the output of `printf` are `3.141590`. But the `assert` in thread function still failed.